# Submit GET form with javascript - CakePHP creating duplicate inputs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I assume it's the Security Component that's creating a duplicate of my input:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('39', array('type'=>'checkbox')); ?>
```

Becomes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="39" id="Form39_" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="39"  value="1" id="Form39"/>
```

Maybe this works fine in most scenarios?  (Cake ignores it?)

But my form is of GET method, so when I submit, I get this:

```
...&39=0&39=1...  in the URL
```

Or, if I don't check the box, I get this:

```
...&39=0  (shouldn't even be there)
```

How can I it to either a) not create a duplicate or b) don't submit both during GET submits?

Comment: why are you using a GET request for a form?

Comment: swiecki - I assume you're joking.  Not that it's funny, but I can't imagine how that could be a serious comment.

Comment: I guess I was merely being curious about what you were using this form for. From the HTML5 spec: `If the processing of a form is idempotent (i.e. it has no lasting observable effect on the state of the world), then the form method should be GET. Many database searches have no visible side-effects and make ideal applications of query forms.
- -
If the service associated with the processing of a form has side effects (for example, modification of a database or subscription to a service), the method should be POST.` Also, I do see now that I worded my question awfully. :(

Comment: swiecki - While I appreciate you taking the time out of your day to write a comment on my question, it is completely irrelevant as to "why" I'm using GET.  I did not ask whether or not I should use POST or GET, nor did I infer that I was curious about when to use or not use POST vs GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->checkbox('39', array('hiddenField' => false));
?>
```

[Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)